# How to make a non-decreasing row in c#

Tags: c#

I have three imaginary numbers, and I need to put them into non-decreasing rows, but I don't know how .

```
    int a, b, c, mak, min, mid;
    a = Convert.ToInt32(tba.Text);
    b = Convert.ToInt32(tbb.Text);
    c = Convert.ToInt32(tbc.Text);
    mak=b;
    if (a > mak)
        a = mak;
    else
        if (c > mak)
            c = mak;
    a=min;
    if (b < min)
        b = min;
    else
        if (c < min)
            c = min;
    c=mid;
    if (a == mak);(a==min)
    a = mid
    if (b == mak) ;(b==min)
    b = mid;
    tbd.Text=Convert.ToString(mid);
    tbg.Text=Convert.ToString(mak);
    tbf.Text=Convert.ToString(min);
```

It says only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement. How can I correct this code to work?

Comment: What do you try to do here: `(a == mak);(a==min)`?

Comment: Are you trying to sort the numbers? You might want to look into methods such as Array.Sort - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - this approach will be really cumbersome with more than 3 numbers

Comment: i was trying to find a middle number and i was thinking that == are representing different i dont have any idea how to find a middle number and i need it to sort this numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that mak should be the maximum, min the minium and mid the middle. If that is right you have to do a view changes:

```
    int a, b, c, mak, min, mid;
    a = Convert.ToInt32(tba.Text);
    b = Convert.ToInt32(tbb.Text);
    c = Convert.ToInt32(tbc.Text);
    mak=b;
    if (a > mak)
        mak=a;
    if (c > mak)
        mak=c;
    min=a;
    if (b < min)
        min=b;
    if (c < min)
        min=c;
    mid=c;
    if (a!=mak && a!=min)
        mid = a;
    if (b!=mak && b!=min)
        mid=b;
    tbd.Text=Convert.ToString(mid);
    tbg.Text=Convert.ToString(mak);
    tbf.Text=Convert.ToString(min);
```

Comment: In this code `mak`, `min`, and `mid` will always be 0 since nothing is ever assigned to them.

Comment: Oh, only edited half of the code and didn't recognize that almost every line makes no sense. Now it should be correct.

Comment: Almost.  The min needs to be compared to a not c since it is initialized to c.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you mentioned the line of code causing the problem. However, these lines of code are invalid:

```
if (a == mak);(a==min)
... 
if (b == mak) ;(b==min)
```

I'm not sure what you hoped to accomplish with them. If you wanted to assign to the variables if the conditions were true, it should be more like:

```
if (a == mak) a=min;
...
if (b == mak) b==min;
```

Comment: with this lines i was wanted somehow to find a middle number i can not find it nohow do you know how to find him

Answer (score 0):

I made the correct code

```
int a, b, c, mak, min, mid;
a = Convert.ToInt32(tba.Text);
b = Convert.ToInt32(tbb.Text);
c = Convert.ToInt32(tbc.Text);
mak=a;
if (b > mak)
    mak = b;
if (c > mak)
    mak = c;
min=a;
if (b < min)
    min = b;
if (c < min)
    min = c;

mid = a;
if (mak != b & min != b)
    mid = b;

if (mak != c & min != c)
    mid = c;

tbd.Text=Convert.ToString(mid);
tbg.Text=Convert.ToString(mak);
tbf.Text=Convert.ToString(min);
```